# ASP.NET MVC - deserializing response from SOAP web service

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, serialization, soap, xml-serialization

This is my code in MVC:

```
    string url = "https://api....";
    HttpWebRequest httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
    httpWebRequest.Method = "POST";
    httpWebRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";

    string postData = "<?xml version=\"1.0\"?>" +
                        "<request>" +
                            "<login>" + Login + "</login>" +
                            "<password>" + Password + "</password>" +
                            "<limit>" +
                                "<offset>10</offset>" +
                                "<limit>10</limit>" +
                            "</limit>" +
                        "</request>";

    try
    {
        using (StreamWriter requestWriter = new StreamWriter(httpWebRequest.GetRequestStream()))
        {
            requestWriter.Write(postData);
        }
    }
    catch (System.Net.WebException ex)
    {
        return null;
    }

    HttpWebResponse httpWebResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();
    Stream responseStream = httpWebResponse.GetResponseStream();
    StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(responseStream);
    var serializer = new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(typeof(Class.hotels));
    Class.hotels hotel = (Class.hotels)serializer.Deserialize(streamReader);
    streamReader.Close();
    responseStream.Close();
    httpWebResponse.Close();
```

I got same functionality in my Windows Phone 7 project (little changes with asynchronous calling) and it's working. I have added classes from WP7 project to MVC and I am trying now in MVC. Everything is working but in final I got hotel with 0 items (but in WP I got items in there). I tried to read `streamReader` to string and I got there right answer so the problem must be with deserializing.

So what could be problem? If class would be wrong I get error message from XmlSerializer, am I right (and in WP it wouldn't be working too)? But I don't know where else could be the problem. Thanks for help

**Edit:**
Part of hotels class:

```
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.Xml", "4.0.30319.17929")]
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
public partial class hotels : object
{
    private int countfield;
    private ObservableCollection<hotel> hotelfield;

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Order = 0)]
    public int count
    {
        get
        {
            return this.countfield;
        }
        set
        {
            this.countfield = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Order = 1)]
    public ObservableCollection<hotel> hotel
    {
        get
        {
            return this.hotelfield;
        }
        set
        {
            this.hotelfield = value;
        }
    }

}

/// <remarks/>
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.Xml", "4.0.30319.17929")]
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
public partial class hotel : object, System.ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanged
{

    private int hotIdField;

    private int hoyIdField;
    ...
    many properties
    ...

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Order = 0)]
    public int hotId
    {
        get
        {
            return this.hotIdField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.hotIdField = value;
            this.RaisePropertyChanged("hotId");
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Order = 1)]
    public int hoyId
    {
        get
        {
            return this.hoyIdField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.hoyIdField = value;
            this.RaisePropertyChanged("hoyId");
        }
    }
    ...
    many getters, setters
    ...
```

and content of response (xml in string):

```
"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\n<hotels>\n    <foundHotels>4655</foundHotels>\n    <hotel>\n        <hotId>12</hotId>\n        <hoyId>1</hoyId>\n        <bookOnline>0</bookOnline>\n        <name>OÁZA Říčany</name>\n        <address>\n            <couId>1</couId>\n            <regId>3</regId>\n            <cotId>51</cotId>\n            <towId>121</towId>\n            <zipId>12093</zipId>\n            <name>OÁZA Říčany</name>\n            <street>V Chobotě 2112</street>\n            <city>Říčany</city>\n            <zip>25101</zip>\n            <country>Česká republika</country>\n            <phone>\n                <number>+420 323 601 170</number>\n                <number>+420 736 679 097</number>\n                <number>724 165 420</number>\n            </phone>\n   ... many properties ...     </hotel>\n    <hotel>\n        <hotId>13</hotId>\n        <hoyId>1</hoyId>\n        <bookOnline>0</bookOnline>\n        <name>Hotel Maxov</name>\n        <address>\n            <couId>1</couId>\n            <regId>14</regId>\n            <cotId>20</cotId>\n            <towId>1317</towId>\n            <zipId>2492</zipId>\n            <name>Hotel Maxov</name>\n            <street>Dolní Maxov 710</street>\n            <city>Josefův Důl</city>\n            <zip>46844</zip>\n            <country>Česká republika</country>\n            <phone>\n                <number>483381085,483381100</number>\n            </phone>\n     ... many properties of another hotel ...        </hotel>\n</hotels>\n"
```

Comment: Have you checked whether `streamReader.ReadToEnd()` returns valid data?

Comment: Yea, that is what I mean whit this: `I tried to read streamReader to string and I got there right answer so the problem must be with deserializing`.

Comment: Could you also add a sample of the XML response and the `Class.hotel` definition?

Comment: No problem with showing. It's just many information in it. Class.hotel and Class.hotels is automatic generated from web service.

Comment: @Bibo does your `hotel` class happen to have any readonly properties that your trying to deserialize?

Comment: Nope, don't have any readonly property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try redefining your classes like this:

```
public partial class hotels : object
{
    private int countfield;
    private ObservableCollection<hotel> hotelfield;

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Order = 0, ElementName="foundHotels")]
    public int count
    {
        get
        {
            return this.countfield;
        }
        set
        {
            this.countfield = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElement(Order = 1,ElementName="hotel")]
    public ObservableCollection<hotel> hotel
    {
        get
        {
            return this.hotelfield;
        }
        set
        {
            this.hotelfield = value;
        }
    }
    // other fields
}

public partial class hotel : object, System.ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private int hotIdField;
    private int hoyIdField;

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Order = 0)]
    public int hotId
    {
        get
        {
            return this.hotIdField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.hotIdField = value;
            this.RaisePropertyChanged("hotId");
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Order = 1)]
    public int hoyId
    {
        get
        {
            return this.hoyIdField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.hoyIdField = value;
            this.RaisePropertyChanged("hoyId");
        }
    }

    // other properties
}
```